# set selected start time as min time for end date in react date picker

Tags: reactjs

Hello i am using React Datepicker for specific time range.

https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-specific-time-range.

Heres is my code:

```
class Location extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       selectedStartDate: '',
       selectedEndDate: '',
        booking: {
            startDate: '',
            endDate: '',
        },
    };

    this.handleStartDateChange = this.handleStartDateChange.bind(this);
    this.handleEndDateChange = this.handleEndDateChange.bind(this);
}


handleStartDateChange(date) {
    var bookingObj = this.state.booking;
    bookingObj.startDate = date;
    this.setState({ booking: bookingObj})
}

handleEndDateChange(date) {
    var bookingObj = this.state.booking;
    bookingObj.endDate = date;
    this.setState({ booking: bookingObj})
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-12 start_boxx">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                        <div className="form-group date_time">
                            <DatePicker
                                className="form-control dtepickr"
                                placeholderText="Click to select start Date"
                                selected={this.state.booking.startDate}
                                onChange={this.handleStartDateChange}
                                minDate={this.state.selectedStartDate}
                                maxDate={this.state.selectedEndDate}
                                showTimeSelect
                                dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm aa"  
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group date_time">
                            <DatePicker
                                className="form-control dtepickr"
                                placeholderText="Click to select end Date"
                                selected={this.state.booking.endDate}
                                onChange={this.handleEndDateChange}
                                minDate={this.state.selectedStartDate}
                                maxDate={this.state.selectedEndDate}
                                showTimeSelect
                                minTime={this.state.booking.startDate}
                                maxTime={this.state.booking.??}
                                dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm aa"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

I want to set my start time as minimum time for end date.
i use minTime and maxTime fumction but does not work.
please help me to get out of this.
thanks

Comment: you missed to add selectedStartDate and selectedEndDate as part of your state. Add those and confirm if it is working

Comment: min and max date is set now but time is not setting up

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to found the native solution without any library and I made it.
Hope that works for you.

My requirement are

1. Min Date is the current date
2. Min Time is the current time for today
3. Max Time will night 11:59 PM for all
4. When you select the next date then you can select any time

```
// initialValue of pickupDate is null
<DatePicker
  selected={values.pickupDate}
  onChange={date => handleChange('pickupDate', date)}
  showTimeSelect
  dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy h:mm aa"
  placeholderText="Pick up date & time"
  isClearable
  minDate={new Date()}
  minTime={
    new Date().getDate() ===
    new Date(values.pickupDate ?? new Date().getTime()).getDate()
      ? new Date()
      : new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0)
  }
  maxTime={new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59)}
/>
```

```
new Date().getDate() === new Date(values.pickupDate ?? new Date().getTime()).getDate()
```

Above I am checking the current date with my state date and my `pickupDate` state is initially `null` that is why I am initially giving the `integer` timestamp to date

```
? new Date() : new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0)
```

and if it true then it will give the current time as `minDate` else it will setHours, minutes and seconds to `0`

Answer (score 0):

You setting your `minDate`/`maxDate` with `state.selectedStartDate`/`state.selectedEndDate` but you don't have such states in your component, they are undefined.

Also, you don't call `super(props)` within the consturctor.

```
class Location extends Component {
  //            v Call props
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      booking: {
        startDate: '',
        endDate: ''
      },
      selectedStartDate: /* Some value */,
      selectedEndDate: /* Some  value */
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: added but time range not set

Comment: How you added, which values? update your questions and maybe add some sandbox

Comment: i use min Time as selected date but i dont want to set max time if i remove maxTime it gives error "Both minTime and maxTime props required"

Answer (score 0):

```
const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(new Date());
const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(new Date());
const [duration, setDuration] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
    const format = "HH:mm";
    const start = moment(startTime, format);
    const end = moment(endTime, format);

    if (end.isValid() && start.isValid()) {
      const duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
      const hours = Math.floor(duration.asHours());
      const minutes = duration.minutes();
      setDuration(
        `${hours.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${minutes
          .toString()
          .padStart(2, "0")}`
      );
    } else {
      setDuration("Invalid time format");
    }
  }, [startTime, endTime]);

console.log(duration)


<ReactDatePicker
                        selected={startTime}
                        onChange={(time) => {
                          console.log("time", time);
                          setStartTime(time);
                          setFieldValue("meetingStartTime", new Date(time));
                        }}
                        showTimeSelectOnly
                        showTimeSelect
                        selectsStart
                        maxDate={new Date()}
                        timeFormat="HH:mm"
                        timeIntervals={15}
                        timeCaption="time"
                        dateFormat="h:mm aa"
                        placeholderText={"Select Meeting Start Time"}
                        className={`border border-1 ${
                          errors.meetingStartTime && touched.meetingStartTime
                            ? "border-red"
                            : ""
                        } rounded-lg w-full px-4 py-1.5`}
                      />

<ReactDatePicker
                        selected={endTime}
                        onChange={(time) => {
                          console.log("time", time);
                          setStartTime(time);
                          setFieldValue("meetingStartTime", new Date(time));
                        }}
                        showTimeSelectOnly
                        showTimeSelect
                        selectsStart
                        maxDate={new Date()}
                        timeFormat="HH:mm"
                        timeIntervals={15}
                        timeCaption="time"
                        dateFormat="h:mm aa"
                        placeholderText={"Select End Time"}
                        className={`border border-1 ${
                          errors.meetingStartTime && touched.meetingStartTime
                            ? "border-red"
                            : ""
                        } rounded-lg w-full px-4 py-1.5`}
                      />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<DatePicker
className="form-control dtepickr"
placeholderText="Click to select end Date"
selected={this.state.booking.endDate}
onChange={this.handleEndDateChange}
minDate={this.state.selectedStartDate}
maxDate={this.state.selectedEndDate}
showTimeSelect
minTime={this.state.booking.startDate}
maxTime={this.state.booking.??}
dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm aa"
disabled={this.state.isEndDateDisable}
```

/>

Comment: You have edit button, do not use answer as comment section